Dropdown menu for survey form that adds new question after selecting yes option - Only CSS
I'm learning html and for a project I'm making a survey form. I want a dropdown menu that when the user selects yes it has new question pop up relating to the subject. How would i do this? I have no knowledge of JavaScript.
Do you own the DLC?

`(select one)
Yes
No


What i want is when someone selects yes other questions will now show relating to the dlc. Will this be possible with only html and css?

I have just posted answer, which is just using CSS, but it has a catch about how your HTML structure should be.

did you happen to get the answer you were looking for?

You can do by validating option value selected for the siblings.
For this HTML structure should have the select dropdown and the questions elements/HTML tags on same level, as in they should be siblings.
Check below:


label { display: block; margin: 40px 0 10px; }

#dlc { display: none; }

.dlc:has(option[value="yes"]:checked) ~ #dlc {
  display: block;
}
<select class="dlc" name="" id="">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<div id="dlc">
  <label for="newq">New Question</label>
  <input id="newq" type="text" placeholder="New Answer Here...">
</div>



Hope this helps, using JUST CSS.

Here you go:


let DLC = document.getElementById("DLC");
for (let choice of document.querySelectorAll("[name=choice]")) {
    choice.addEventListener("change", function() {
        DLC.classList[((choice.id === "yes") === choice.checked) ? "remove" : "add"]("invisible");
    });
}
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
Do you own the DLC? `(select one) 
<label for="yes">Yes</label><input name="choice" type="radio" id="yes">
<label for="no">No</label><input name="choice" type="radio" id="no" checked>
<select id="DLC" class="invisible">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>



Explanation:

Javascript

we get the elements whose name is choice
we loop the result set iterating it with a variable called choice
we get the select whose appearance we want to toggle
we check whether the id is yes and is checked or is not yes and is unchecked, in which case we remove the invisible class showing it, or adding the invisible class, hiding it
we have a change event for both checkboxes


CSS

we have an invisible class to easily hide elements by adding this class or showing elements by removing it


HTML

Created a dummy structure for this purpose



In CSS you can create a next sibling selector rule with pseudo-selectors, but unless you are okay by holding the click button, I advise against it in this case.

You can use HTML input radio buttons for this.
This snippet uses the format you have shown, creating it by setting the actual radio buttons to have opacity 0 and position absolute so they take up no space, what the user sees is their related labels.


<style>
  .extraquestion {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .question:has(.yes:checked) .extraquestion {
    display: block;
  }
  
  [name="yesno"] {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  label:has(.yes:checked) {
    background: green;
    color: white;
  }
  
  label:has(.no:checked) {
    background: red;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="question">Do you own the DLC? (select one)
    <label for="yes"><input type="radio" name="yesno" class="yes">Yes</label>
    <label for="no"><input type="radio" name="yesno" class="no">No</label>
    <div class="extraquestion"><label for="extra">Please answer this extra question
<input type="text" name="extra" id="extra">
</div>
</div>
</body>



Note: instead of showing the standard radio buttons, the snippet colors the selected button label.
